# Supersized Slider + Wp E-Commerce

Tags: supersized

I've adapted the Supersized slider to work with WP e-commerce to create a featured product slider.

It works perfectly for products that were attributed to the featured category before I installed the slider, but as soon as I add a new product into the category, it breaks.

Could someone have a quick look at my code to see if I can do it a better way and find out why it's going wrong? It doesn't seem logically possible to me!

Can take a look at my source here: http://thetechhunter.co.za/

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 

        jQuery(function($){
            $j.supersized({

                //Functionality
                slideshow               :   1,      //Slideshow on/off
                autoplay                :   1,      //Slideshow starts playing automatically
                start_slide             :   1,      //Start slide (0 is random)
                random                  :   0,      //Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
                slide_interval          :   10000,  //Length between transitions
                transition              :   1,      //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed        :   500,    //Speed of transition
                new_window              :   0,      //Image links open in new window/tab
                pause_hover             :   0,      //Pause slideshow on hover
                keyboard_nav            :   1,      //Keyboard navigation on/off
                performance             :   1,      //0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
                image_protect           :   1,      //Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript
                image_path              :   'img/', //Default image path

                //Size & Position
                min_width               :   0,      //Min width allowed (in pixels)
                min_height              :   0,      //Min height allowed (in pixels)
                vertical_center         :   1,      //Vertically center background
                horizontal_center       :   1,      //Horizontally center background
                fit_portrait            :   1,      //Portrait images will not exceed browser height
                fit_landscape           :   0,      //Landscape images will not exceed browser width

                //Components
                navigation              :   1,      //Slideshow controls on/off
                thumbnail_navigation    :   1,      //Thumbnail navigation
                slide_counter           :   1,      //Display slide numbers
                slide_captions          :   1,      //Slide caption (Pull from "title" in slides array)
                slides                  :   [       //Slideshow Images


                                    <?php $my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'wpsc-product', 'wpsc_product_category'=>'featured-products' ) ); while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();?>

                                                    {image : '<?php echo wpsc_the_product_image(); ?>', 
                                                     title : '<div class="slidecaptioninside"><a href="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?></a><br /><span style="color: #111;"><?php echo wpsc_the_product_price(); ?></span></div><br /><div class="slidedescription"><?php $excerpt = wpsc_the_product_description(); echo string_limit_words($excerpt,50)."...";?></div>', 
                                                      url : '<?php echo wpsc_the_product_permalink(); ?>'},  

                                    <?php endwhile; ?>    
                                            ]

            }); 
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this plugin installation [WP Supersized](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-supersized/)

You can also follow these tutorial links, I hope this is what you need and let me know.

[How to integrate Supersized in wordpress](http://www.worldinmyeyes.be/1534/)

In the plugin, the author seems to be using 'function slides_list()' to output an array of images and removing the comma for the final slide.

If you already solved this - could you please post your answer for the benefit of others